# HEREDOC syntax PHP erroring on first line

Tags: php, html, heredoc

I am trying to write the below code in Nowdoc syntax but directly under the
`$str = <<<HTML`

I have an error on the first line.  I have no idea why.  I'm using this in another project and its fine.

```
$str = <<<HTML
    <div>
        <div class="product-thumb">
            <div class="ribbon">
                <img src="/img/affiliate.png"  alt=""/> 
            </div>

            <a href="">
                <header class="product-header">
                    img  
                </header>
                <div class="product-inner">
                    <h5 class="product-title">client name</h5>
                    <div class="product-meta">
                        <ul class="product-price-list">
                            <li><span class="product-save">saving</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <p class="product-location"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> cat</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
HTML;
```

I get the following error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable
>   (T_VARIABLE) or heredoc end (T_END_HEREDOC) or ${
>   (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN) in

Comment: maybe use `<?php`

Comment: so what error ...

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko thank you.  Apologies this is  already inside a <?php tag

Comment: @Oliver  My IDE is not telling me its just erroring with a red line and pointing to no solutions or why.

Comment: @Oliver   actually I have an error Ill write it in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

End of file means the script has either `a ?>` before that part, the script is  dying or you have same hidden char before `$str`. Try deleting contents before `$str` (even if you don't see a char).

Comment: thank you there was some blank spaces.  that seems to of fixed it

Comment: Nice! Could you please mark as accepted answer?